# Finding the Date id Future or Not

Tags: php, html, cakephp, date, joomla

I need to find the date is expired or not.

Here is my Date. But it was not working for me,

```
$ActualDate    = "2013-03-19 05:05:23";
$ExpiryDate    = "2013-04-18 05:05:23";

$elapsedTime = new DateTime($ActualDate);
$now         = new DateTime($ExpiryDate);
echo ($now < $elapsedTime ? 'Future' : 'Past');
```

I cant get the accurate result... if any one knows this, please post a answer it will helpful for me.

Comment: You don't need to use `DateTime` object if dates are stored in such strings. You can compare them directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `$elapsedTime` is set to `$ActualDate` and `$now` to `$ExpiryDate`. You probably want to swap them.

Comment: ...or change `<` to `>` in the last line.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$expires_at = new DateTime('2013-04-19 05:05:23');
$now        = new DateTime();

echo $now < $expires_at ? 'Future' : 'Past';
```